# Does $\theta(n)$ = $1/x$ make any sense?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

So, I asked this question on a discrete structures exam today, which I apparently didn't give enough thought to:

$f(x) = (5x^2 + 6x + 2)/(x^3 + 4x^2 +x)$

Find the correct theta notation for the function.

So, I believe it is easy to create an upper bound around $1/x$ since we can show $f(x) \leq 2/x$ for sufficiently large $x$.  I don't know that a lower bound can exist since $C$ must be positive and would need to be zero for a proper $\Omega(n)$ lower bound.

First, am I correct about the non-existence of a tight bound or am I missing something here?

Second, is this the only reason this is a Mickey Mouse type question or what else am I missing here?  It seems like it could be possible for a particular algorithm to have a $1/x$ complexity.

Comment: I don't believe $f(x)\le(2/x)$ for large $x$. I'd believe $(5+\epsilon)/x$ as an upper bound.

Comment: You don't want to be writing $\theta(n) = 1/x$ and $\Omega(n)$, first because it doesn't convey the idea you think it does and second because there is no $n$ anywhere in the problem.  If you want to say that "the function $f$ has a Theta behavior of $1/x$" (or whatever) then you would write $f(x) = \Theta(1/x)$.

Comment: @Antonio: Better yet, $f(x)\in\Theta(1/x)$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I see what you are saying about $5 + \epsilon$ being the upper bound.  Also, Antonio, I agree with what you said.  I see where I went wrong in both cases.  But, is $f(x)\in\Omega(1/x)$?  It seems to be bounded below by 0, so I would guess it does not since $0*f(x)=0$ for any function with a mapping to the reals for instance.  Does there exist an $\Omega(x)$ for this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $f(x) = g(x)/h(x)$, where $g(x)$ is the numerator and $h(x)$ is the denominator. Hopefully we can all agree that $g(x) = \Theta(x^2)$ and $h(x) = \Theta(x^3)$: for example, for $x \geq 1$ we have
$$
5x^2 \leq g(x) \leq 13x^2 \\
x^3 \leq h(x) \leq 6x^3
$$
It follows that $f(x) = \Theta(1/x)$: for example, for $x \geq 1$ we have
$$
\frac{5}{6} \frac{1}{x} = \frac{5x^2}{6x^3} \leq \frac{g(x)}{h(x)} \leq \frac{13x^2}{x^3} = 13 \frac{1}{x}.
$$
The same calculation we did here shows that (abusing notation) $\Theta(\alpha(x))/\Theta(\beta(x)) = \Theta(\alpha(x)/\beta(x))$, where in this case $\alpha(x) = x^2$ and $\beta(x) = x^3$.